# Locating Without WiFi/Celluar API

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I know it sounds weird. It happens that those Locating APIs regarding WiFi/celluar assistance are disabled in most Android handsets in China. That is, I could hear the callbacks of GPS_PROVIDER when I was out of the building. But if I was in the building, I would never hear the callbacks of NETWORK_PROVIDER. As a result, my app won't be able to locate if put indoor. (I did some experiments with handsets shipped from the states. My app located perfectly well with the NETWORK_PROVIDER if put indoor.)

My guess is that those Chinese Android handsets have sort of *castrated* the Android OS so that any API related to WiFi/celluar assistance locating has been removed.

But my app still needs to locate. A city-level accuracy will do.

So my question is, is there any possible solution for my situation. Right now I'm considering:

1. IP address reverse-lookup. But the accuracy is far worse than city-level.
2. Let my app collect any necessary information (such as router MAC address, celluar tower info) and send them to a third-party server. That server would locate and send back location info to me.
3. Find (magically) a third-party SDK and hopefully that SDK would do the trick.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @jeffamaphone: Yes. But a user might come up with a false city name just to earn certain benefits from us. ;)

Comment: What about the last known location from GPS_PROVIDER? It should be fairly accurate, and you can look at the time stamp of the last time it was updated. Also I doubt the OS is castrated (though it could be), but rather that the cell networks don't support location lookups (the carrier has to support it I believe).

Comment: Ah, well, you need to fully specify the constraints in which the problem you are attempting to solve exists.  :)

Comment: I don't think this is a Chinese problem. There seem to be lots of issues with the Network provider not getting updates at times. I'm struggling with trying to get good location tracking on Kindle atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP lookup is fine. You can also try skyhook wireless's location SDK: [here](http://www.skyhookwireless.com/developers/sdk.php)

iOS in the early days are using them, and they are actually better/more accurate than Google's location service.

Answer (score 1):

It is definetly possible. You look at the services of [Imere's ULaP](http://www.imere.com).